# Excel Cell Comments Are White When Opened in Calc?

Tags: 10.04, openoffice.org

I have an Excel 2003 (`.xls`) spreadsheet that I created on my Windows box. I tried to open it on Open Office's `Calc` program, and it looks like all the cell values / formatting is indeed there.

Yet, for some reason, all the comments that are in the cells appear to be **white text on yellow background** -- which makes them impossible to read.

Any hints how to fix this bug? (I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the latest version of [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download)? They're essentially the same thing, but LibreOffice is the non-Oracle-owned, open source one.

Comment: Yes, the same problem is with `LibreOffice`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried saving it as an Excel 97/2000/XP compatible file? I find that they generally work much better with LibreOffice.

Comment: @user11833 You should probably [report](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) this bug so the devs can work on a fix.

Comment: Do you still get this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please report this bug so it can be fixed:

[How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

The LibreOffice team I'm sure would be keen to solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been reported to Launchpad as bug [1022640](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1022640). The fix will be available in LibreOffice 4.0.4 which will be available in Saucy and probably Raring. A fix might be prepared for earlier Ubuntu releases, please see the bug report for more information.

A [workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1766616&p=10858660#post10858660) is to change the colour settings in LibreOffice:

> Go to 'Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice.org -> Appearance -> Notes Background' and 'Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice.org -> Appearance -> Comment' and change them to something that will work for you.

A second [workaround](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=41232#p189886) is to install a macro, which resets the font colours for comments.

Both of the above workarounds have been created for OpenOffice.org but they should for for LibreOffice.