# Adding code to .gtkrc-2.0?

Tags: configuration

Somebody recommended that I add the following code to `.gtkrc-2.0`:

```
style "tooltips" {
    fg[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }
    text[NORMAL] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }
}

widget "gtk-tooltips*" style "tooltips"
```

How do I go about this? I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "Add the following code" sounds pretty straightforward.

Comment: I am having a problem with Open Office's `calc` program. see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44479/excel-cell-comments-are-white-when-opened-in-ubuntus-calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then type

```
gedit ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

to start the text editor `gedit` with the file already opened. Then copy and paste the code, save the file, log out and back in again.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that the file is empty. Does it make sense? (I just want to make sure I am editing the right file).

Comment: Yeah, it isn't there by default. If it already would be there, you would see something when directly open it like described.

Comment: Thank you. I made the change, yet, it still did not solve my problem. any idea you can help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/44479/excel-cell-comments-are-white-when-opened-in-calc